# Set backgraund image position in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any way to set button background image position or button imageView in swift?
I have tried frame.origin but it did not help me.

Answer (score 2):

You can set `imageEdgeInsets` for this button.

```
button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

More information: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uibutton_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/imageEdgeInsets

Comment: in this method image resizes. i don`t need that.

Comment: Perhaps you button is too small. Try adjusting is size.